# Adding a volume to an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon ec2 instance that keeps running out of disk space. It looks to me like the solution is to add another volume on with more disk space to the existing EC2 linux machine. However I was not able to find guidence as to how this works. If I add a second volume will the machine automaticaly store files ont that vlumne when it runs out of space on the current volume or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a new volume, you can try expanding the volume: [Modifying the Size, IOPS, or Type of an EBS Volume on Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modify-volume.html)

You do not have to stop the instance to expand the volume, you can do it whie the instance is running.

Comment: I tried what you recommended. The volume expanded but the root drive is a partitiom in the vloume which did not expand which means I cannot actualy use the extra space. To get the partition to expand is a complicated procedure requires turning off the server and detaching the volume etc. At this point will be better served spinning up a whole new server